# Is is possible to email a specific view within a list?

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-calendar

I've got a color coded calendar based on several overlays which are just different views filtered to only show specific categories within the list. I can enable the incoming email setting for this list but that just sends it to the "all items" view. Is there a way to allow the list to receive an email for a specific view?

Answer (score 1):

The view is just a filter of the all items view and when the incoming email is received, it will automatically add to the calendar and all views. 
So the answer, as far as I know, is you cannot send it to a specific view. However, think of a way to show the incoming email on that specific view using metadata value and hide it from the other views based on the same metadata value.